# SEO Google not noticing my website

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, search-engine

I quite recently launched a website (3-4 weeks ago).

I send in sitemap and added website to google webmaster tools and analytics

And it is still doing really bad in the Google Search engine for some reason. 
The url is rondleidingleiden.nl Which means tourleiden however for this search term (rondleiding leiden) the website is on page 4 at the bottom of the page!

According to SEO by yoast my website is fine.
First webpage looks quite like this

1/2 left
306 words and containing quite some keywords

1/2 right
[BLOG]

Maybe that has something to do with it?

Hope u guys could help me out here.
website is http://www.rondleidingleiden.nl

Many Thanks!

Comment: How about adding: **<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure SEO question without a programming component.

Comment: well the programming aspect is how Google views this part [BLOG]

Comment: @daanaan — That isn't programming.

Comment: @Quentin Alright, but do you know where I can ask SEO questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info

Comment: 3-4 weeks ago <--- thats the key... be patient...
Your sitemap containts only the menu elements. Make new sitemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cononical tag to the ip address 46.19.218.7, it might be flagging it as **duplicate content**. Also add some **social media integration** (like, share buttons) as google loves them. You site is also very heavy, frontpage is around 3.3Mbs (google hates heavy pages) try using a **caching** plugin like "w3total cache" which will cache your pages in browsers and also cache it on the server, which will reduce the 1.5 second lag on the wait time that you have. W3total cache will also **minify** your media files. It also have cdn integration option, so you can automatically host all the media files on a **cdn** which will make it faster. I also noticed your website is preety heavy on **code to text ratio**, reduce your inline styles and host them in separate css file. 
It will obviously take some time to get ranked, **backlinks** are very important as google look at them a factor for relevance and authority, so try to get some decent backlinks from high ranking websites.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set some backlinks on other pages to your page. Google finds new websites by jumping from link to link. If there is no link pointing on your website, google won't be able to find it. there are special link archives online where you can register your website to add a backlink.